# How to combine multiple arrays as a string

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have multiple different parts of data that I am trying to combine into one single array, as though I'm writing a string to it and am trying to find a method of doing so. My current attempt is shown below, but of course doesn't work. I was hoping someone could point me into the correct direction

```
newline = "%s %s\t%d\t%d %d %d  \t%.2f\n",
arr_student[printing].fname, arr_student[printing].sname, arr_student[printing].UP_no, arr_student[printing].marks_1,
arr_student[printing].marks_2, arr_student[printing].marks_3, arr_student[printing].average_mark;
```

Comment: I think you forgot to copy the function call

Comment: It's unclear what you really want do. Print an array of struct ? Store array of struct under a string format ? Or is there nothing to do with string ? Please provide input and output expected.

Comment: Can't you get the job done using `strcpy()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to create a string with that information, you should use the `sprintf` function which will generate a string according to your format string and format parameters:

**Edit**: As pointed out by @PeteKirkham, you should use the `snprintf` function instead, which allows you to specify the maximum number of bytes (or characters) to write to the output string

```
char newline[100]; // or however many characters you want to allocate for
snprintf(newline, 100, "%s %s\t%d\t%d %d %d  \t%.2f\n",
arr_student[printing].fname, arr_student[printing].sname, arr_student[printing].UP_no, arr_student[printing].marks_1,
arr_student[printing].marks_2, arr_student[printing].marks_3, arr_student[printing].average_mark); // again, replace 100 with however many characters you are expecting to write
```

Comment: snprintf is preferred since the 1990s.

Comment: @PeteKirkham you're absolutely right I guess I learned outdated syntax, just updated my answer